# React native - alternative for IOS Tabs in Android?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to find any kind of alternative for tabs in Android...
I tried the "ToolbarAndroid" component, but I don't understand how to render a dynamical content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you're looking for? https://github.com/AlbertBrand/react-native-android-tablayout